# What is difference between .h5 and .hdf5 format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pre-trained-model

Suppose we have saved our model as h5 then we can load model using load_model function of keras..
I have gone through multiple github links where the author provides weights file (.h5 or .hdf5 file).

So can we use those pretrained weights/model using load_model?

what is difference between load_model and load_weights?

Can I load weight file with load_model (keras) or should I use (load_weight). If we are loading weight then we mush also load whole architecture of the model..

Please provide deeper understanding by taking some example..

Answer (score 5):

Defining the model

```
model = ...
```

Training the model

```
model.fit...
```

Saving the model:

```
model.save('model_topology.h5)
```

Saving the weights:

```
model.save_weights(`weights.h5`)
```

When calling load_model(), if you want to run inference, you have to call load weights to load the pretrained weights.

```
model = load_model('model_toplogy.h5)
model.load_weights('weights.h5)
```

This is true when dealing with models saved in the HDF5 format (.h5).

`Tensorflow` provides another format for saving models: the `saved_model` format.
The save_model format saves the model topology (graph) and trained parameters (weights and biases) in a directory. This enables loading a model with one command.

`model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_dir)`

About `h5` and `HDF5`:
`h5` is just a shortened extension for files saved in the HDF5 format.

Comment: got your point. Upvoted.
If we are using Modelcheckpoint then can we save weights in either format(.h5 or .hdf5)?
Also, if I am not wrong.. then suppose if we are not saving the weights file instead saving model only then we can directly load model using load_model.. right

Comment: What is difference between .h5 and .hdf5 format?